# Regex split at every character and remove all whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, split, removing-whitespace

right now I use `string.split("(?!^)")`and it splits 'abc' into "[a, b, c]" which is perfect.

But now there is the possibility that the given string is `abc.....` (stackoverflow doesnt allow so many spaces, so . equals a whitespace). I still want [a, b, c] so how can i change the regex that it splits the whitespaces at the end "away"?

Comment: trim the whitespace first: `string.trim()`

Comment: Using a regex to split a string into individual characters is kind of like using a chainsaw to separate toothpicks. An alternative is  `String.toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the string first:

```
String string = "      abc     ";
String[] stringArray = string.trim().split("(?!^)");
```

[Demo](http://runnable.com/VBWtm1m7evhfVjPR/stackoverflow-com-questions-25834428-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

First remove all white spaces and then split

```
string.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?!^)")
```

Comment: OP: "splits the whitespaces *at the end*"

Answer (score 0):

You could use String's trim method to remove whitespace before and after a given String.

Answer (score 0):

Through regex only,

```
String s = "abc    ";
String[] tok = s.split("\\s+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[a-z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
```